# How to generically attach and display tags to models in Django?

Tags: django

I want to write a very basic tagging app in Django that is almost identical to the [Generic Foreign Key example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1) in the docs (django-tagging and django-taggit are overblown for me).

The challenge is displaying all the items of a particular tag, no matter its content type, in the tag detail template.

My guess was to make a Tag with name and slug, then TaggedItem with ctype/object_id/content_object. Blog post gets a many-to-many with Tag, and a signal to save a new TaggedItem. Maybe TaggedItem should've gotten a slug? and maybe Post should've gotten a generic relation instead of a many to many? My query guess is in `tags/views.py` under `context['tagged_items']`. That's where I'm stuck now.

`# blog/models.py:`

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('tags.Tag', blank=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-published']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog.views.post_detail', args=[str(self.slug)])
```

`# tags/models.py:`

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from blog.models import Post


class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tags.views.tag_detail', args=[str(self.slug)])


class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


def create_tagged_item(sender, **kwargs):
    if 'created' in kwargs:
        if kwargs['created']:
            instance = kwargs['instance']
            if instance.tags.all:
                content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)
                object_id = instance.id
                tagged_item = TaggedItem.objects.create(content_type=content_type, object_id=object_id)


post_save.connect(create_tagged_item, sender=Post)
```

`# tags/views.py:`

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from .models import Tag
from .models import TaggedItem


class TagListView(ListView):
    model = Tag


class TagDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Tag

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TagDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tagged_items'] = TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_object__tags__in=self.object.slug) # ????
        return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with Timo Zimmermann's approach: looping through possible tags on a generic Entry item. http://www.screamingatmyscreen.com/2012/6/django-and-generic-relations/ Admin friendly and no need for a `TaggedItem`!

```
class TagDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Tag

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TagDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        item_list = []
        for item in ActivityItem.objects.all():
            if self.object in item.tags:
                item_list.append(item)

        context['item_list'] = item_list
        return context
```

Thanks to @DanielRoseman and @Ben for weighing in.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any kind of relationship between Tag and TaggedItem, which is making things difficult.

It seems to me that the M2M should be between those two models, and not on Post at all. The whole point is that anything can "be" a tagged item, hence the generic relationship, and that item can have multiple tags. With that, you can then do:

```
tag = Tab.objects.get(slug=my_slug)
tagged_items = TaggedItem.objects.filter(tags=tag)
content_objects = [item.content_object for item in tagged_items]
```

But actually, if you're going for simplicity I don't know why you don't use exactly the code from the docs, without the separate Tag model at all. You'll end up with many TaggedItems with the same tag slug/name, but that's OK: you can still do

```
tagged_items = TaggedItem.objects.filter(slug=my_slug)
```

and get the content_objects as before.

Comment: I presume you mean filter where you've put get in TaggedItems?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, thanks. It's still not clicking for me, though. I don't see how removing Tags from Post helps. I want to tag any content object in the admin. An M2M between Post and Tag is the way to do that. I can see that an M2M between Tag and TaggedItem makes some sense, but couldn't figure out how to save it on an instance. `TaggedItem.objects.create(content_type=content_type, object_id=object_id, tags=instance.tags.all)` wasn't right. Storing `TaggedItem.objects.filter(slug=my_slug)` didn't make sense to me at all. Each tagged item will have many tags...overloading would limit it to one.